# Get songs from sd card not updated each time in local db

Tags: android, sqlite, audio, android-mediaplayer

Am getting all songs from sd card and store it into local db
 Now i delete songs using file explorer
 When I open my app am getting updated songs but in my local db how can I update those songs

For ex.am having 4 songs.I stored those in my local db.I added 2 songs let say example a.mp3 and b.mp3 in playlist.I have added those in playlist table of my db.in file explorer I mean outside of my app I have deleted a.mp3 song.when I open my app using media scanner I get 3 songs which is updated one but what about the same deleted song in my playlist table in sqllite.Please anyone help me to resolve this issue

Comment: The external file explorer is not responsible for deleting the song from your db. It's you, who has to do that.

Comment: @PrerakSola yes.But if i delete it from file explorer.when i open my app by using media scanner i get the updated datas but in my local db it have old datas.how can i update my local db.because i have playlist table and it also get affect if the song was not avail